# What Chinese lesson (Category of words) should I be studying?

Tags: translation, meaning, writing, learning

[image: I have absolutely no idea about the words that are circle in black. So the cycle starts, I will use Pleco dictionary to scan the word and I will know the meaning of that word for a while. Obviously, I wouldn't be able to do that on test time]

I have absolutely no idea about the words that are circled in black. So the cycle starts, I will use Pleco dictionary to scan the word and I will know the meaning of that word for a while. Obviously, I wouldn't be able to do that on test time.

Comment: indicated circles cut through words:  公园，风景；骑，自行车；游览 correctly marked as one word;价钱｜便宜 （price|cheap) correctly marked; 13:自行车，１４：美丽，１５：便宜，１６：健康

Comment: @user6065 Thanks for the answer, but what are all of these words about? Do they fall under one category of words?

Comment: category: basic everyday vocabulary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have difficulties identifying words and recognizing patterns.

eg:

- 香山公`园风`景美丽。 vs
- 香山 ／ **公园** ／ **风景** ／ 美丽。

*The landscape at Xiangshan Park is beautiful.*

公园 is a very common noun. You should be able to identify it. And look at the sentence rhythm: 2 / 2 / 2 / 2.

- 骑自行车: If you don't know this expression, you already have a hint in the question. The expression appears twice, and 自行车 alone, without 骑, appears in the table of 8 words. Reading a problem carefully is always a good idea.

So there's a hint: 自行车 is a single, 3-character, word. So you have a structure like this: 骑+自行车. If that doesn't announce `Verb+Noun` I don't know what does. You might not know what a 骑兵 is, but since you didn't circle 马 I assume you know what it means. 骑 has the horse radical, so it's not too wild to imagine it has to do with riding . Especially with a `xx车` vehicle... Context is always important.

What you need to do is:

- Improve your vocabulary. Read more. Spend time with a dictionary. Paper dictionaries are usually more useful for learning. If you spend time looking up characters by hand, you'll get more familiar with their radicals and stroke numbers, stroke orders. And reading through a paper dictionary is far more interesting than online.
- Focus. Don't panic. As you have discovered, just scanning words in an app doesn't work. Identify patterns. I've mentioned 骑自行车, but #14 for instance is just a question of writing down the exact same word as in the original text: 香山公园风景........[美丽]. How hard can that be?

Good luck.

**Addendum**

Look up the vocabulary requirements of HSK 1 & 2 to start. Make sure you know all the words in there.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's begin with the question itself.
Below are the meanings of the words you encounter:
健康 - noun, "health"
马 - noun, "horse"
安全 - adj./noun, "safe/safety"
美丽 - adj., "beautiful"
环境 - noun, "environment"(may have better translation when used elsewhere)
难看 - adj., "ugly"
便宜 - adj., "cheap"
自行车 - noun, "bicycle"
The text is about riding a bicycle to Xiangshan. It has several advantages, as the text indicates. The question requires you to fill the blanks with the words above, which can be easily found "as is" in the original text.

Answer (score 0):

```
香山公园风景美丽
```

The above sentence can be broken down into 4 parts: 香山，公园，风景，美丽. "园风” is incorrect. The first three words are nouns, while the last is an adjective.

```
骑自行车
```

The above sentence can be broken into 2 parts: 骑，自行车. The first word is a verb, while the last word is a noun.